# Powershell Remove Characters between 2 commas

Tags: powershell

I would like to remove everything after the first comma, but keep that comma, then then remove the second comma and keep everything after that. So, a name like LEE, M.D., SCOTT would look like LEE, SCOTT. Thx

Comment: `'LEE, M.D., SCOTT' -replace ',\s(\S\.?){2},',','`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to split at the commas, and re-assemble using a format string:

```
$text = 'LEE, M.D., SCOTT'

'{0}, {1}' -f $text.split(',')[0,2]

LEE,  SCOTT
```